# How to create time since last event in unbalance panel data in R?

Tags: r, panel-data

I have unbalanced panel data with a binary variable indicating if the event occurred or not. I want to control for time dependency, so I want to create a variable that indicates the number of years that have passed since the last event. The data is organized by dyad-year.

Here is a reproducible example, with a vector of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

```
   id year onset time_since_event
1   1 1989     0                1
2   1 1990     0                2
3   1 1991     1                0
4   1 1992     0                1
5   1 1993     0                2
6   2 1989     0                1
7   2 1990     1                0
8   2 1991     0                1
9   2 1992     1                0
10  3 1991     0                1
11  3 1992     0                2
```

˚

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
year <- c(1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1989,1990,1991,1992,1991,1992)
onset <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0)
time_since_event<-c(1,2,0,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2) #what I want to create
df <- data.frame(cbind(id, year, onset,time_since_event))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`, create a run-length id grouping variable ('ind') based on the 'onset' column using `rleid`.  Grouped by 'ind' and 'id' column, we assign the 'time_since_event' column as the row sequence where 'onset' is not equal to 1.  In the next step, replace the 'NA' elements with 0.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, ind:=rleid(onset)][onset!=1, time_since_event:=1:.N , 
     by = .(ind, id)][is.na(time_since_event), time_since_event:= 0]

df
#     id year onset ind time_since_event
# 1:  1 1989     0   1                1
# 2:  1 1990     0   1                2
# 3:  1 1991     1   2                0
# 4:  1 1992     0   3                1
# 5:  1 1993     0   3                2
# 6:  2 1989     0   3                1
# 7:  2 1990     1   4                0
# 8:  2 1991     0   5                1
# 9:  2 1992     1   6                0
#10:  3 1991     0   7                1
#11:  3 1992     0   7                2
```

Or it can be made compact.  Grouped by `rleid(onset)` and 'id' column, we negate the 'onset' (so that 0 become TRUE and 1 FALSE), multiply with row sequence (`1:.N`) and assign (`:=`) it as the 'time_since_event' column.

```
setDT(df)[,time_since_event := 1:.N *!onset, by = .(rleid(onset), id)]
df
#    id year onset time_since_event
# 1:  1 1989     0                1
# 2:  1 1990     0                2
# 3:  1 1991     1                0
# 4:  1 1992     0                1
# 5:  1 1993     0                2
# 6:  2 1989     0                1
# 7:  2 1990     1                0
# 8:  2 1991     0                1
# 9:  2 1992     1                0
#10:  3 1991     0                1
#11:  3 1992     0                2
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`.  We group by 'id' and another variable created (by taking the difference of adjacent elements in 'onset' (`diff`), create a logical index (`!=0`) and `cumsum` the index).  Within the `mutate`, we multiply the row sequence (`row_number()`) with the negated 'onset' (just like  before), and remove the 'ind' column using `select`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id, ind= cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(onset)!=0))) %>% 
    mutate(time_since_event= (!onset) *row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-ind) 
#     id  year onset time_since_event
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)            (int)
#1      1  1989     0                1
#2      1  1990     0                2
#3      1  1991     1                0
#4      1  1992     0                1
#5      1  1993     0                2
#6      2  1989     0                1
#7      2  1990     1                0
#8      2  1991     0                1
#9      2  1992     1                0
#10     3  1991     0                1
#11     3  1992     0                2
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id, year, onset)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the function rleid()? Its not in my data.table package.

Comment: @user46257 Which version of data.table you have ?  It is available from `v1.9.6`..  If you don't have that function, you can still use the `dplyr` method.